# Unable to open file while writing php file

Tags: php, fopen, file-handling

I am trying to use fopen and fwrite

```
$book="http://bittotb.com/synthesis_study_material/student_admin/include/uploaded/epub/923960_hotel (1).epub";
$path=$book.".php";
$myfile =fopen($path, "w");
$txt = "<?php include('hello.php'); ?>";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
```

when I just write the file name in fopen like

```
$myfile =fopen("abc.php", "w");
```

then it's making a file in the same directory but I want to make that file in another directory. while using path it's not working if I echo the $path then I am getting

```
http://bittotb.com/synthesis_study_material/student_admin/include/uploaded/epub/923960_hotel (1).epub.php
```

this is correct file name and path but still, it's giving me Unable to open the file and my folder permission shows 0777

Comment: I guess the whitespace may be a problem or the `/` - create hash from this string and use it as file name

Comment: You probably have to [create the containing directory](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php)  `http:/bittotb.com/synthesis_study_material/student_admin/include/uploaded/epub` first.

Comment: now i had used str_replace and replace space from _ but problem is still there

Comment: Remember 0777 means every user on the machine can read, *write* and execute it (execute for directories means read file list). If you are using some public hosting, other websites can access your data.

Comment: Unix mode is sum of these values: 1=execute, 2=write, 4=read. For three digits, the first means owner, second owner group and third everyone else. There can be one more digit on the left (you have 0=default) that modifies behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use path on the server, not the URL of page.

For example, you page can have URL `http://example.org/index.php`. The file can be on the server known as `/var/www/example.org/index.php`.

Use this code to determine your directory:

```
<?php
echo getcwd();
```

If the code above shows `/var/www/example.org/`, file `http://example.org/test.php` has file path `/var/www/example.org/test.php`. But it is better to use relative paths. (see below)

---

If you have page `http://example.org/index.php` and you want create `http://example.org/test.php`, use this:

```
$file = fopen("test.php", "w");
fwrite($file, "<?php echo 'Hello World'; ?>");
fflush($file);
fclose($file);
```

---

If you want to write to file `http://bittotb.com/synthesis_study_material/student_admin/include/uploaded/epub/file.php` from script `http://bittotb.com/synthesis_study_material/student_admin/module/corses/file.php`, use relative path:

```
$file = fopen("../../include/uploaded/epub/file.php", "w");
// ...
```

Comment: yes it will make but my file is in http://bittotb.com/synthesis_study_material/student_admin/module/corses/file.php and i want to make this file in http://bittotb.com/synthesis_study_material/student_admin/include/uploaded/epub/file.php

Comment: @vivekmodi but you have to work with paths on the server, not URLs.

Comment: how can we make a file with permission of 0775 so any one can open this file

Comment: @vivekmodi Use [chmod](https://php.net/chmod). Example: `chmod("../../foo.txt", 0775)` (Always use zero before the number!) `0775` means owner and group can read, write and *execute* and others can read and *execute* the file. Do you want the file executable?

Comment: yes i want the file executable but after add chomd in my code i am  getting 500 internal server error

Comment: Do you see it only on the script, only on the page that generates it or on all pages?